# puppeteer cluster _ no sand box option is not working on launch

Tags: puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

this is my config on the puppeteer cluster :

```
const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
  concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
  workerCreationDelay: 2000,
  puppeteerOptions:{args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']},
  maxConcurrency: numCPUs,
});
```

when I try to run in my host it comes with error:

> Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
> [1014/132057.583562:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as
> root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180.

but according to the documentation of [puppeter cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#clusterlaunchoptions) you can pass the puppeteer option in **puppeteerOptions**

why passing options are not working?